# boost::interprocess shared memory and R bigmemory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, r

I have a server client system where the server is a vc++ program and the client is in R.
Can I use a shared memory between these two? with boost::interprocess at the vc++ end and R bigmemory at the R end?

the server and the client are on the same pc

Comment: Please don't cross-post on R-help and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You get a very firm *Maybe!* for that.

The [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) package (or group of packages, these days) does use the mutexes from Boost -- see the [synchronicity](http://cran.r-project.org/package=synchronicity) package that it builds upon.  Why don't you start with a simple prototype of sharing a 100 x 2 matrix and see how far you get?  Michael will probably be glad to help your further once you demonstrated some initial viability.